# Visualizar documento word/pdf no browser

Tags: c#

Olá, senhores.
Preciso visualizar documentos salvos em formato, Word e PDF browser, contudo o usuário não pode imprimir. Esse formato pode ser por exemplo em html ou flash.

Encontrei esse projeto https://code.google.com/p/flexpaper/, contudo não conseguir.
Eu sei, que não existe uma forma de tratar isso 100%, exemplo o usuário pode tirar um print, mais desejo dificultar o máximo, já que é uma regra da empresa esse bloqueio.

Comment: Olha, depois que você coloca alguma coisa no browser essa coisa passa a estar no computador do cliente. Não existe como bloquear 100% nada, se realmente o cliente quiser ele consegue imprimir, salva, etc. Qual é o nivel de bloqueio que você quer?

Comment: bloquear a impressão e não permitir salvar o arquivo na máquina do cliente

Comment: Em que plataforma é pra fazer isso Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.NET?

Comment: Cara, como o Ricardo disse. Não tem como você prevenir 100% de tudo... Você pode evitar a impressão para usuários mais comuns, mas se você pegar outro desenvolvedor ou alguém que entenda um pouco mais ele vai conseguir imprimir e salvar

Comment: Estou fazendo em asp.net mvc Murilo.
È para enganar os usuários mais comuns KhaosDoctor.

Comment: Tem algumas api pagas que fazem isso, como a http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/demo/

Comment: Encontrei esse projeto open source, https://code.google.com/p/flexpaper/, que acredito que possa resolver. Mais nao estou conseguindo usar com asp.net, alguém já usou ou sabe como fazer para usar? Tentei seguir esse exemplo http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/jj12345678910/testing-openrowset-sharp47-bulk-insert-bcp/

Comment: Na verdade o browser usa no Windows o ActiveX (ou seja é necessário o msword instalado e para pdf o adobereader), mas eu não sei que tecnologia de browser esta usando. Você também poderia tentar um componente de conversão pra html (não será algo fácil). Poderia dizer qual componente de browser usar.